# Loop through object Javascript and create Jsx and display

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have 2 sets of the object here
set1

```
  var set1 = {
       men:[{ code: "men", title: "Men" }]
       women: [{ code: "women", title: "women" }],
       animal:[{ code: "animal", title: "animal" }],
    };
```

set2

```
var set2 = {
  men: { value: "men", label: "Men", type: "select", "options": [ {label: "boy", value_string: "1"}, {label: "Guy", value_string: "2"}] },
  women: { value: "women", label: "Women", type: "select", "options": [ {label: "lady", value_string: "1"} , {label: "girl", value_string: "2"}] },
  kids: { value: "kids", label: "Kids", type: "select" ,"options": [ {label: "infant", value_string: "1"} , {label: "baby", value_string: "2"}] },
};
```

I have 3 different scenarios here where I want to loop or compare set1 with set2 and display data in JSX in React from set1. set2 is dynamically created on click on the button.

scenario 1:
If set1 key and set set2 key are matching I want to display values from which doesn't match. example - men and women are matching keys of both sets,so I want to display values of **kids**.
That is kids.label and values inside the option. label infant and baby.

scenario 2:
If my set1 is empty I want to display only the first object set from set1. For example-  if set1 is empty I want to display only **men** values that are men.label(Men) and men.options.label(boy , Guy) from set2.

scenario 3
if set1 has no matching key with set 2 display first set from set1. example animal in set1 is not matching with any key in set2. so display the first set of objects from set 1.That is **men** .men.label(Men) and men.options.label(boy , Guy) from set2.

Comment: What's the issue you're facing? You can check the conditions for scenario 2 and 3 first and finally the scenario 1.
If you're struggling with starting it, you should look at [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop.

Comment: im not getting how to loop and check. Can you write a small code so i can check. @Siddharth

Comment: This should help you out a bit [https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-water-hj2vq](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-water-hj2vq)

Comment: @Siddharth JSON.stringify() should not be used for Object comparison

Comment: @HelmerBarcos I'm just comparing the keys, can you tell me what would be the issue in that?

Comment: @Siddharth Assuming the keys are longer in set1 this always will return false. And if the keys are the same but the values are different it also will return false.

Comment: @HelmerBarcos I agree with the first part, I've updated the sandbox to incorporate that case. But since I was comparing just the keys, value comparison doesn't come into scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```js
    console.log('\n\n\n Starting scenario 1')
    var set1 = {
      men:[{ code: "men", title: "Men" }],
      women: [{ code: "women", title: "women" }],
      animal:[{ code: "animal", title: "animal" }]
    }

    var set2 = {
      men: { value: "men", label: "Men", type: "select", "options": [ {label: "boy", value_string: "1"}, {label: "Guy", value_string: "2"}] },
      women: { value: "women", label: "Women", type: "select", "options": [ {label: "lady", value_string: "1"} , {label: "girl", value_string: "2"}] },
      kids: { value: "kids", label: "Kids", type: "select" ,"options": [ {label: "infant", value_string: "1"} , {label: "baby", value_string: "2"}] }
    }

    const set1Keys = Object.keys(set1)
    const set2Keys = Object.keys(set2)

    // scenario 1
    const notMatchingKeys = set2Keys.filter(key => !set1Keys.includes(key))
    const results = notMatchingKeys.length ? notMatchingKeys.map(key => set2[key]) : null

    console.log(results) // you could map over the results
    
    console.log('\n\n\n Starting scenario 2')
    // scenario 2
    const emptySet1 = {}
    if (Object.keys(emptySet1).length === 0 && set2Keys.length) {
        // get value from first key on set2
        console.log(set2[set2Keys[0]])
    }

   console.log('\n\n\n Starting scenario 3')
   // secanrio 3 

   if (set1Keys.filter(key => !set2Keys.includes(key)).length){
        console.log(set1[set1Keys[0]])
   }
```